# How to remove socket.io EIO and other parameters from url

Tags: socket.io

When I configure socket-io with the following options:
{ url: 'ws://localhost:8888', options: {path: '/chatws', transports: ['websocket'], reconnectionAttempts: '3'}}

I get the following error
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8888/chatws/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 501

If I use other frameworks that do not add any parameters then it works.

How does one remove the EIO and all query parameters from the URL?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party. I am going to answer your question in two parts. First, I will start with paths. According to the [Kafka Server Path Documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-options/#path) you need to configure both paths for your server and your client. Here is an example for just paths:

### Path

***Server config***

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, { path: "/custom-path/" });
```

***Client config***

```
const socket = io({ path: "/custom-path/" });
```

### EIO (Engine.IO)

EIO (Engine.IO) is your transport system. According to [Kafka Server Transportation Documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-options/#transports) to modify this you need to configure both the client and the server. Here is another example:

***Server config***

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, { transports: ['new-websocket-name'] });
```

***Client config***

```
const socket = io({ transports: ["websocket"] });
```

### lets put it all together.

***Server config***

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, { 
 transports: ['new-websocket-name'],
 path: "/custom-path/"
});
```

***Client config***

```
const socket = io({
 transports: ["websocket"],
 path: "/custom-path/"
});
```

Answer (score -4):

That's not the case.
While you are implementing only websocket based transportation, you need to configure that in both sides. As by default, socket.io try to establish the connection using long polling.

Server-side implementation:

```
const express = require('express')()
const server = require('http').createServer(express)
const io = require('socket.io')(server,{transports:['websocket']})
```

Client Side Implenation :

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
const socket = io('http://localhost:8080',{transports: ['websocket']})
```

This worked for me!

Comment: This does not answer the question - How does one remove the EIO and all query parameters from the URL?